# Setting "--keepalive-time" for curl in php

Tags: php, curl

Some backstory here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/714273/curl-returning-error-52-or-56-with-rest-api-call-spanning-more-than-5-minutes

So, I have this REST API call that I need to make via PHP and the only way I can get it to work via the CLI is setting the `--keepalive-time` for CURL. So how do I do that in PHP? Here is the (censored for creds) working API call via CURL directly:

```
curl --max-time 600 -k -o dump.txt --connect-timeout 0 --keepalive-time 30 --trace-ascii trace.txt --trace-time -X GET -H "tenant-code: 1cmPx7tqVDVTdN1GSelwycFUmICmASnLCmNQsV72" -H "Authorization: Basic JxHAsXeUiHMRkS8Msiu6pWb3PvY20p6am3QvXCY3knXTAntlxTBS3EyEDgly" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 'https://api.endpoint.com/API/v1/system/users/search?groupid=555'
```

The `--max-time` and `--connect-timeout` values don't seem to matter as much (as long as they are within bounds of what I need) but the `--keepalive-time` seems to be required to get the data back from the call. Here is some test code I am using:

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.endpoint.com/API/v1/system/users/search?groupid=555";
$session = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
$headers = array(
        'tenant-code: 1cmPx7tqVDVTdN1GSelwycFUmICmASnLCmNQsV72',
        'Authorization: Basic JxHAsXeUiHMRkS8Msiu6pWb3PvY20p6am3QvXCY3knXTAntlxTBS3EyEDgly',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Accept: application/json');
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($session);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($session);
var_dump($httpcode, $output, $session, $headers, $url);
?>
```

I added `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);` and `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);` for testing but they don't seem to have any effect on my issue. So what is needed to get this handled by CURL in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.5 or greater (currently 5.5, 5.6, & 7) built with cURL 7.25.0 or greater, you can set these cURL options in PHP to match the `--keepalive-time` parameter (PHP <= 5.4 did not have these cURL options available):

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, 30);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL, 15);
```

The `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE` constant in libcurl corresponds to the `--keepalive-time` command line option for `curl`.

See the cURL docs regarding [CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.html), [CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE.html), and [CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL.html) for more info.

Note: These options are not available and can't be used if you have PHP 5.4 or lower.

Comment: I upgraded CURL to `7.44.0` and setup php to use that version. I added that code to my test code and ran it. Still fails after 5 minutes. I didn't get any errors so I assume its working but for whatever reason that isn't solving my issue.

Comment: I double checked in the curl source code that passing `--keepalive-time` argument sets `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL` in the underlying call so I looked at the PHP source code and it turns out what is happening is that if PHP doesn't recognize the curl option (which it doesn't here) then it never calls `curl_easy_setopt` on the underlying handle so those options are ignored.

Comment: So there is no way to get CURL/PHP to set that parameter?

Comment: No, but I checked again and it looks like these options are available in PHP 5.5, 5.6, and 7 Alpha so if you are able to upgrade to PHP 5.5 then you can use these [curl TCP options](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/curl/interface.c#1210)

Comment: I added `defined('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE') || define('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE', 213);
defined('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE') || define('CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE', 214);` and `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE, 30);` to my test code and upgraded to PHP 5.5.28 and I am still seeing the same issue. Do I need to make changes to the code or is there another issue on the system? CURL is at 7.44.0.

Comment: You can ignore the part about defining those constants since they exist in PHP 5.5 and greater.  All you should have to do is call `curl_setopt`.  I would suggest trying to set `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE` to `1`, `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL` to `30` and also `CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE` to `30` as well.  I think the issue may be with the idle connections.  For clarity I'll re-write the answer now to remove the old info.